# Creating swift framework in AppCode

Tags: swift, appcode

It is possible to create Swift frameworks (modules) like in XCode: [File] -> [New target] but using AppCode? 
If I doing this using Xcode all working perfectly but if I try to do this in AppCode (in project settings) then I receive errors like: 'No such module [name]' after import.

What receipt is for this?

Comment: It might (or might not) be possible, but I prefer to set and configure targets in Xcode. Also I use Interface Builder in Xcode rather than AppCode's terrible version of it. Once set up, I proceed in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was **not** possible to do before and I still don´t think *AppCode* has support to add targets unfortunately. Could not find any information that they support this on their site either. So the answer will be **no**.

Comment: I also looked for something but.. I found nothing :/ Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible in appcode:
Open project settings (cmd+;) -> plus button on bottom -> select new target

[image: New target selection]